# How can i add or update products and prices in my list?

Tags: javascript

Pretty new to javascript, i want to add and update my list but it doesn't work.

I tried adding following code but it didn't work

```
Product.prototype.addProduct = function() {
    var elol = document.getElementById("lijst");
    var nieuwNaam = document.createElement("li");
    nieuwNaam.textContent= this.naam;
    elol.appendChild(nieuwNaam);
    var nieuwPrijs = document.createElement("li");
    nieuwPrijs.textContent= this.prijs;
    elol.appendChild(nieuwPrijs);
}


Product.prototype.getProducten = function() {
    return this.naam + "(&euro; " + this.prijs +")";
}
```

This is the document i want wish would work propperly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="oefwinkel.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      winkel.addProduct("Potlood", 10);
      VulLijst();
      var elBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
      elBtn.onclick = VoegProductToe;
    });

    function VulLijst() {
      var elol = document.getElementById("lijst");
      var producten = winkel.getProducten("</li><li>");
      if (producten.length > 0) {
        elol.innerHTML = "<li>" + producten + "</li>";
      } else {
        elol.innerHTML = "";
      }
    }

    function VoegProductToe() {
      var naam = document.getElementById("txtNaam").value;
      var prijs = document.getElementById("txtPrijs").value;
      winkel.addProduct(naam, prijs);
      VulLijst();
    }

    function Product(naam, prijs) {
      this.naam = naam;
      this.prijs = prijs;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div><label for="txtNaam">Naam:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNaam" /></div>
  <div><label for="txtPrijs">Prijs:</label>
    <input type="number" id="txtPrijs" /></div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Toevoegen/Updaten" />
  <ol id="lijst">
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

There is no list output how do i correct this?..

I really can't find the solution, what did i miss.. huh?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

## Explained

I will openly admit, I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, I assume that's due to a language barrier my side though, I'm not sure of the natural language that you use on a daily basis, i.e. some of the variable names seem unclear to me, but that's my problem, not yours! :)

Anyway, I used some guess work to figure out what you're trying to achieve, and I assumed that you're simply trying to have some sort of product list where each product has a name and a price attached to it?

You want to be able to add a product to the list, based on two input fields, then some button to add to/update that product list.

I've broken up the code into a couple of simple functions, with this solution you can add/remove as many functions, classes or whatever you want. In this answer you can clearly see that there's some `render` function, and some `onUpdate` function, I just went with these generic names for the sake of simplicity.

If you have any issues with this solution, please provide as much feedback as possible! I hope that it's been of some help one way or another.

```js
// A simple product list.
const ProductList = () => {
  const products = [];
  let el = null;

  // What you wish to return, aka an object...
  return {
    addProduct: (name, price) => {
      products.push({
        name: name,
        price: price
      });

      onUpdate();
      render(el, products);
    },

    setRoot: root => {
      el = root;
    },

    // removeFromList, etc... 
  };
};

// A simple on update function.
const onUpdate = () => {
  console.clear();
  console.log('Update!');
};

// A 'simple' render function.
const render = (el, products) => {
  if (el == null) return;

  const template = obj => `<li>${obj.name} &euro;${obj.price}</li>`;
  let html = '';
  products.forEach(product => html += template(product));
  el.innerHTML = html;
};

// A function to dispatch some event(s).
const dispatchEvents = products => {
  const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  const price = document.getElementById("price");
  const name = document.getElementById("name");

  // Just an example.
  const isValid = () => {
    if (price.value != '' && name.value != '') return true;
    return false;
  };

  // Handle the on click event.
  btn.onclick = () => {
    if (isValid()) {
      products.addProduct(name.value, price.value);
      name.value = '';
      price.value = '';
    }
  };
};

// A simple dom ready function.
const ready = () => {
  const products = ProductList();
  products.setRoot(document.getElementById("productList"));

  products.addProduct('Demo', 10);
  products.addProduct('Other', 19.99);

  dispatchEvents(products);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="name">name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="price">Prijs:</label>
  <input type="number" id="price" />
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Update" />

<ol id="productList">
</ol>
```

Comment: `el` is undefined.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl My bad, I had built it initially with nearly **everything** within the ```ProductList``` function, I've just made some minor updates to it. Thanks for the pointer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You had a few things missing,

1. The HTML code.
2. The `winkel` object was undefined.
3. The `VulLijst` function was doing nothing... because `addProduct` was taking care of this already.
4. You are relying on the instance fields (`this.naam` and `this.prijs`), but what you want to do is pass in method parameters (external variables).

As for updating, you will need to store a list of Products, clear the child elements of `lijst`, and re-add the items that represent the list.

**Note:** One thing I am confused about is why you named your class—that represents a list—`Product`, when it should really be an `Inventory` that allows you to ADD `Product` objects.

#### Code

```js
// Uncaught ReferenceError: winkel is not defined
var winkel = new Product();

function Product(naam, prijs) {
  this.naam = naam;
  this.prijs = prijs;
}

Product.prototype.addProduct = function(naam, prijs) {
  naam = naam || this.naam; // Default or instance field
  prijs = prijs || this.prijs; // Default or instance field
  console.log(naam, prijs);
  var elol = document.getElementById("lijst");
  var nieuwNaam = document.createElement("li");
  nieuwNaam.textContent = naam;
  elol.appendChild(nieuwNaam);
  var nieuwPrijs = document.createElement("li");
  nieuwPrijs.textContent = prijs;
  elol.appendChild(nieuwPrijs);
}

Product.prototype.getProducten = function(naam, prijs) {
  naam = naam || this.naam; // Default or instance field
  prijs = prijs || this.prijs; // Default or instance field
  return naam + " (&euro; " + prijs + ")";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  winkel.addProduct("Potlood", 10); // Why are you adding a product to a product?
  var elBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
  elBtn.onclick = VoegProductToe;
});

function VoegProductToe() {
  var naam = document.getElementById("txtNaam").value;
  var prijs = document.getElementById("txtPrijs").value;
  winkel.addProduct(naam, prijs);
}
```

```css
label { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<label>Product</label>
<input id="txtNaam" value="Something" />
<input id="txtPrijs"value="1.99" />
<button id="btn">Add</button>
<br/>
<ul id="lijst"></ul>
```